# SQL Query From multiple table sum column and display

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database with 2 different tables

One table (players) contain a column nammed "totaldeplata" that contains numbers (price)
Other table (vanzari) contain a column like the first one nammed "totaldeplata" it hase the same value inside numbers (the price)

i manage to display the sum of all column for each table like this:

```
 <div align="right">   Total Comenzi luna curenta: <i><strong>
 <?php    
 $query = "SELECT * FROM vanzari WHERE MONTH(datainregistrarii) = 
 MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())";
 $query_run = mysql_query($query);

 $qty= 0;
 while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query_run)) {
     $qty += $num['totaldeplata'];
 }
 echo $qty;

   ?></strong>  </i> Lei
    </div>
```

But this, display only the sum of one table, so i have to write the same code to display the sum of other column in the secound table (in this case the players table)

I need to sum all the numbers from columns "totaldeplata" from tables: vanzari and players, and display them as one number (to sum all the numbers and display them)

Actualy Sum numbers from columns "totaldeplata" from both tables "vanzari" and "players" and display them.

Any ideea how to do that? :)

Comment: Please stop using PHP's ancient, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (SELECT SUM(field1) FROM table1) + (SELECT SUM(field2) FROM table2) as result

**According to your above code and table name.**

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM vanzari) + (SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM players) as result";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run); 
$sum = $row['result'];
echo "sum of two different column from two tables : "+ $sum;
?>
```

Comment: could you please be more precisley? :)

Comment: Check above answer. i hope this will help you